# Visual Studio 2015 - "Get"-window not responding

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I use VS 2015 RC for a while now and now I face the first issue. I started VS, clicked on my recent solution, but then the following Window opened:

[image]

The problem is that what ever button I press (Get, Cancel, Close Button) and which CheckBox I checked, VS does not respond accordingly. It's not frozen, but the behavior is like you just put nothing in to your Button_Click Method. I am basically stuck with this window now. Restarting VS and rebooting did not help. Is there a file that I can delete to get out of this cycle? Did somebody face this exact problem?

Comment: Is it a "vanilla" VS 2015 install or do you have any extensions or add-ins installed?

Comment: Pretty much vanilla. I only have Web Essentials installed. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a Repair for Visual Studio 2015 RC in Program and Features.

/Sorry comments not working for me right now

Comment: Repairing did not help, unfortunately. @Unlockedluca

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Source of the problem was that the workspace was on another user account (lets call it contoso\John) on my local machine. This is an old user though. Contoso\John was migrated to a "fabrikam" domain. As a result the current user, the one that I work with daily is fabrikam\John. Because the SIDs are the same, both accounts have access to each others userprofile folder. After some usage VS seems to have a problem opening the workspace that is inside the contoso userprofile from the fabrikam account, though.

What I did:
Logged in as "contoso\John", checked in the last changes. Then I created a new workspace on the fabrikam userprofile and mapped it to my project on TFS. Then I logged back in with the fabrikam account, started VS, chose the new Workspace and then opened the solution. Now there is again the "Get"-window, but this time it responds to the Get-command. Everything gets loaded from TFS and is working as expected.

-> The Get-Window perhaps had permission issues with the workspace on the other userprofile, but did not throw any exception/error message. This could be improved by the VS team I think.